# Compiling CUDA with clang on math functions

Tags: c++, cuda, clang

Compiling the following CUDA code *helloWorld.cu* with clang-11,

```
int main() {
    return max(1.0f, 2.0f);
}
```

, using command *clang++-11  -o helloWorld helloWorld.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 -ldl -lrt -lcudart_static -pthread -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64*, encountered the error:

```
helloWorld.cu:2:12: error: no matching function for call to 'max'
    return max(1.0f, 2.0f);
           ^~~
/usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/__clang_cuda_math.h:194:16: note: candidate function not viable: call to __device__ function from __host__ function
__DEVICE__ int max(int __a, int __b) { return __nv_max(__a, __b); }
...
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/include/crt/math_functions.hpp:1079:31: note: candidate function not viable: call to __device__ function from __host__ function
__MATH_FUNCTIONS_DECL__ float max(float a, float b)
...
```

Note that the matching function was actually located correctly by the compiler (ie, "math_functions.hpp:1079:31"), but was mistakenly inferred as a "_*device*_" function.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is host code and it is not syntactically valid C++. That code should not compile, and the compiler behaviour is correct. The code should look like this in order to compile:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    return std::max(1.0f, 2.0f);
}
```

i.e. you have to actually include the standard library header which defines the `max` function, and you have to use the correct namespace. C++ has no built-in `max` function. CUDA does. All you are seeing is an artifact of the clang CUDA compilation trajectory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was aware of the use of `std::max`, but as I understand it, CUDA also implements its own math functions (ie, those in *math_functions.hpp*) which can be used in host code since they're `__host__ __device__`. Actually my code was able to use CUDA's `max` if compiled using nvcc (`nvcc -ccbin clang++ helloWorld.cu -o helloWorld`).

Comment: You understand wrongly. All that happens is that the nvcc c++ front end  will silently import `<algorithm>` when it performs its template overlay magic to get device code to work. CUDA does not overload or modify any math library functions in host code. You are not compiling CUDA code here. The nvcc CUDA front end simply has better standard library integration than the clang CUDA front end does. IF you write broken code, you should expect it not to compile and be pleasantly surprised and then worried when it does compile

Comment: Cool it makes sense. I got this issue when using clang to compile the *simpleMultiCopy* example from CUDA-10.2_Samples. We're too spoiled by nvcc. :)

Comment: That is basically the summary. nvcc does all sorts of magic which most front ends don't and sometimes it makes code that shouldn't compile work. Even code written by NVIDIA employees. It also sometimes breaks and blows up code that it should be able to compile. Double edged sword and all that